# Get all results from a table which doesn't have that combination in another table

Tags: sql, oracle, join, union

I have two tables on Oracle. Say:

```
table1:
id    varchar2,
name  varchar2,
phone number,
age   number,
a     varchar2,
b     varchar2,
c     varchar2

table2:
z varchar2,
a varchar2,
b varchar2,
c varchar2
```

I'm supposed to get all results from `table 1` that don't
have a combination of `a`, `b`, `c` on `table 2`.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you want a `NOT EXISTS`

```
SELECT *
  FROM table1 t1
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
      FROM table2 t2
     WHERE t1.a = t2.a
       AND t1.b = t2.b
       AND t1.c = t2.c )
```

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if you want this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.a=t2.a AND t1.b=t2.b AND t1.c=t2.c
WHERE t2.z IS NULL
```

Comment: +1 For showing there's more than one way to get things done. As per requirements, I would change it to `select t1.* from...`

Answer (score 3):

You can use the **exists** clause.

```
Select *
from table1 t1
where not exists
 (select * from table2 t2
  where t1.a = t2.a
  and t1.b = t2.b
  and t1.c = t2.c)
```